# Compute the dimension of the subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $P_n$ denote the linear space of all real polynomials of degree $≤ n$, where $n$ is fixed. Let $S$ denote the set of all polynomials $f$ in $P_n$ satisfying $f(0)+f'(0)=0$. Compute dim $S$.

The answer is apparently $n$, but I do not understand why it is not $n+1$. The set $\{1, t, t^2,..., t^n\}$ spans $S$, does it not? In which case the dimension is $n+1$.

Comment: The dimension of all polynomials is $n+1$ but not all satisfy the constraint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $\{1, t, t^2,..., t^n\}$ can't span $S$ since $1\notin S$ and $t\notin S$.
Thus, $\dim S\neq n+1$. Indeed, if it were true, then $S$ would be all $P_n$ and we just saw that it's not the case.

Now, to prove that $\dim S = n$, note that if $f(t) = a_0 + a_1 t + a_2 t^2 + \dots + a_n t^n\in P_n$, then $f(0) + f'(0) = 0 \iff a_0 +a_1 = 0\iff a_0 = -a_1$. Thus, $S$ is exactly the set 
$$\left\{f(t) = -a_1 + a_1 t + a_2 t^2 + \dots + a_n t^n = a_1(t-1) + a_2t^2 + \dots + a_nt^n,\; a_1,\dots,a_n\in \Bbb R\right\}$$
This proves that $\{1-t, t^2, t^3, \dots, t^n\}$ spans $S$. I let you prove that it's a linear independent family, thus a basis of $S$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(t) = a_0 + a_1t + \cdots + t^n$ be a polynomial in $P_n$. Then $f(0) = a_0$ and $f'(0) = a_1$. So your restriction $f(0) + f'(0) = 0$ implies that $a_0 = -a_1$. Then any polynomial in $S$ is fixed in one variable. so the dimension decreases by one:  $\dim S = n$.

Comment: That seems to make sense, but what is the spanning set then?

Comment: @JohnArg Think about the elements in your spanning set. The only two that do not satisfy your restriction are $t$ and $1$. But the element $t-1$ does. So remove the former two and add the latter and you have your spanning set. (Prove this!)